# Inject dynamically some content on a listbox and get it back with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms, html

I've created a webpage which uses JQuery to redirect the content of a form to another webpage using PHP to connect to a database to find some content and put it back on the first page.

Eveything works great (thanks to the help of followers of stack overflow :-) ) but now I'd like the following : I'm asking for the postal code of a city, if I'm lucky this postal code is unique (only one city has it) but it also happens that a postal code is the same for several cities so I'd like in that case to display a listbox for the user to choose his/her city.
Does someone has an idea of how to do this ?

my code :

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/" id="myform">
   <input type="text" name="postal_code" id="postal_code" placeholder="Search..." />
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
  <!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
  <div id="result"></div>

<script>
$('#myform').submit(function() {
   var url = 'target.php';
   var postal_code = $('#postal_code').val();
   $.post( url, { postal_code: postal_code },
      function( data ) {          
          $( "#result" ).empty().append( data );
      }
    );
   return false;
});
```

target.php

```
<?php
try
{
   $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
   $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'root', '', $pdo_options);
   $response = $bdd->prepare('SELECT city FROM city_list where postal_code = ?');
   $response->execute(array($_POST['postal_code']));
   echo '<ul>';
       while ($data = $response->fetch())
       {
   ?>
          <br/>The city you entered the postal code is : <?php echo $data['city'];  
       }
       $response->closeCursor();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        die('Error : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

EDIT:

This is the code ok for my needs. I'd only to make some very minor changes from Jules' code to make it ok (for an unknow reason his answer worked perfectly for him but not for me :-) )

```
<?php
try {
//Get the postal code:
$postcode = $_POST['code_postal'];

//Make MySQL connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());

//Select the database
mysql_select_db("site_artisans_amélioré");

//Do your query based on the postcode...
$query = "SELECT ville FROM liste_communes_code_postaux where code_postal = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($postcode) . "'";

//Return the response in a variable
$data = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
//echo "Num rows: " . mysql_num_rows($data);

//Check how many rows the query returned. If more than 1 that means several cities
//exist for one postcode, so you should show a listbox.
//If not, just return the ville name
if (mysql_num_rows($data) > 1) { ?>
    <select name="cities">
<?php  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['ville']?>"><?php echo $row['ville']?></option>
<?php  } ?>
    </select>    
<?php }
else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
    echo $row['ville'];
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
   die("Error : " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: and if there are many cities `$data['city']` is an array or the long string?

Comment: Returning a list is a good idea, but in your **target.php** you open the `<ul>` tag, but you don't fill it with `<li></li>`'s nor do you close it with a `</ul>` tag. So I'd return a `<ul><li>New York City</li></li>Washington D.C.</li></ul>` list and indeed, put it into the **result div**. So you're doing good. I don't see what you'd need help with.. : )

Comment: @k102 It is a string in that case.

Comment: @Jules Thanks Jules :-). The thing is that I'd like to display a listbox when there are several cities for the sames post code for the user to choose his/her city.

Comment: @Bruno So you fixed it. The issue thus was that I was using the shortened PHP opening tag `<?` where you had to use `<?php`  ?? If you are running your files on your local server, you can enable short tags by opening your php.ini and set `short_opentag=On`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which library you are using for your Database queries, so I'll do it in Pseudo-code and mysql_query..

**target.php**

```
<?php
try {
    //Get the postal code:
    $postcode = $_POST['postal_code'];

    //Make MySQL connection
    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die (mysql_error());

    //Select the database
    mysql_select_db("mydatabase");

    //Do your query based on the postcode...
    $query = "SELECT city FROM city_list where postal_code = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($postcode) . "'";

    //Return the response in a variable
    $data = mysql_query($query);

    //Check how many rows the query returned. If more than 1 that means several cities
    //exist for one postcode, so you should show a listbox.
    //If not, just return the city name
    if (mysql_num_rows($data) > 1) { ?>
        <select name="cities" multiple="multiple">
    <?  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {  ?>
            <option value="<?=$row['city']?>"><?=$row['city']?></option>
    <?  } ?>
        </select>    
 <? }
    else {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
        echo $row['city'];
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Error : " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

I hope you catch my drift and you can complete it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for you code. I've pasted it and I don't understand why it doesn't work (nothing happens).

Comment: Well, because the code is not complete. If you want I can edit the post to complete it.

Comment: I'd appreciate it a lot because I've tried to adapt it with my data and it doesn't work.I've been searching and I don't find the origin of the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer. Have a look at it, modify it a bit to match your needs and let me know if it solves your issue. :)

Comment: Thanks for you code but it still doesn't work (nothing happens) and I don't know why.

Comment: You should debug it. Make sure if your db connection is correctly made. Echo your query and see if that one is correct (try copy-pasting it into PhpMyAdmin or whatever you are using). Echo the `mysql_num_rows` to see if something has effectively been fetched. Test your JQuery code and put an `alert(data);` before the `append` to see if any data has been returned. Etc... The idea behind the code is correct. Maybe there is some small issue that is keeping it from working. But that's up to you as I cannot see your entire code. Or create a JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your times and answers. As soon as I find the solution I'll post it !

Comment: @Bruno let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2224/discussion-between-jules-and-bruno)